# Possible to add letters to existing strings in Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

is it possible to add numbers to existing strings in a `listbox`.
I can do it in a `treeview`, like below;

```
treeView1.Nodes[0].Text = treeView1.Nodes[0].Text + "2,";
```

So the string on the text would be "JOHN DOE - A" after a `button click`

EDIT 1 :
I have it kind of working;

```
 var words = new List<string>();

        if (ckbAnswerA.Checked)
            words.Add("-A,");

        if (ckbAnswerB.Checked)
            words.Add("B,");

        if (ckbAnswerC.Checked)
            words.Add("C");

        treeView1.SelectedNode.Text =  string.Join(" ", words);
```

but it completely removes the original text, it should be

JOHN DOE - A,B,C but it returns `-A,B,C`

Comment: Its not quite clear what you want for me, please show the before - after more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few options for doing this, one being outlined in Roma's answer, another is to use the `+=` operator, like so

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Text += String.Join(" ", words);
```

Using the method in Roma's answer, is would instead be

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text + String.Join(" ", words);
```

The part that you were missing is that you are assigning the text to the joined string, but forgetting to first add the original string to the start of it.

This is what the `+=` does for you.

In addition to this, though not a syntax error, if both boxes B and C are ticked but A is not, the dash will not be displayed because it is added one when box A is ticked, it may be worth adding it before you check instead.

Comment: Thanks, but when i click answer B, it turns A,B ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? could you give more information on what happens now, maybe with your updated code?

Comment: it returns  `JOHN DOE - A, A,B` when i have both `ckbAnswerA and ckbAnswerB checked`.

Comment: Based on the code shown that would suggest that ticking box A produces `- A,` but ticking box B mistakenly produces `A,B`

Comment: Correct, that is what happens?

Comment: Is it possible that you could use a break point on the line that adds the strings together, and find out what the List `words` contains?

Comment: i used a breakpoint on ` treeView1.SelectedNode.Text =  string.Join(" ", words);` it just returned `Question1`

Comment: The issue seems unclear now, as this has gone on it has changed substantially, consider closing/deleting this and creating a new question or editing this one.